# directly create pdf through pdfjet library on end user's pc in gae java application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf-generation

I want to output the content of some analysis done by my java application (on Google App Engine) to a PDF using PDFJet library... I want that the file should be directly created on the end user's pc. Is it possible to do this, and any code sample would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Arvind.

Comment: Why do you want the PDF "directly created on the end user's PC"? What's wrong with generating it on the server and sending it to them?

Answer (score 1):

in your servlet,

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

  // set content type so client will see the file download dialog
  response.setContentType("application/pdf");

  // generate pdf content
  PDF pdf = new PDF(response.getOutputStream());
  ...

  // writes file to client
  pdf.flush();
  pdf.close();

}
```

disclaimer: i didnt test the above code.